# Metric on $[0,1)$ that is not complete nor totally bounded

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples, complete-spaces

I am looking for a metric on $[0,1)$ that is not complete nor totally bounded. $[0,1)$ with the Euclidean distance is not complete but totally bounded, other norms are equivalent. With the discrete metric $[0,1)$ is complete. The only idea I am left with is defining a metric with a function for example $d(x,y)=\lvert \arctan(x) - \arctan(y) \rvert$ but it not easy to guess the right one. Any ideas ?

Comment: What about you consider the mapping $t \mapsto \dfrac{1}{1-t}$ so that $[0, 1)$ transforms to $[1, \infty)$ and then $d(t_1, t_2)$ is the Euclidean distance between $\frac{1}{1-t_1}$ and $\frac{1}{1-t_2}$?

Comment: Maybe try $|\tan ( {\pi \over 2} x) - \tan ( {\pi \over 2} y)|$.

Comment: Take one of the above but set the distance from 0 to a non zero element to be 12.

Comment: I guess you are looking for a metric which is equivalent to the Euclidean metric. If so, edit your question. If you accept any metric (inducing a possibly exotic topology), also mention this in your question.